# do PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebView on Windows7-64bit works with SSL sites?

Tags: ssl, pyqt, qtwebkit

I can browse unprotected sites, but trying to open an "https" one results in these messages:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_error_string
```

After that, something inside qt freeze.
My Windows QT/PyQT installations are from standard Riverbank' packages. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working solution in the [riverbank mailing list archive](http://old.nabble.com/QWebView-and-https-td28519684.html): ignore all ssl errors:

```
    [...]
    self.connect(myWebViewControl.page().networkAccessManager(), 
        SIGNAL("sslErrors (QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &)"), 
        self.sslErrorHandler)

def sslErrorHandler(self, reply, errorList): 
    reply.ignoreSslErrors()
    print("SSL error ignored")
```

**UPDATE**: I don't know why but after some weeks I got those ssl errors again, btw I think this time I found the correct solution in [this post](http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html): I got the "*Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0a*" setup from [here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and, as requested, the "*Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)*" from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf), and they solved my problems.

Comment: Can you flesh this example out a bit more? What kind of class is the "self" referring to? Could you give a full working example?

Comment: well, "self" is just a QDialog on which I placed the webview control, and after connecting the signal I simply call a myWebViewControl.load(). the target is the facebook graph authorization url (https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?lot_of_params). if I comment out the reply.ignoreSslErrors() call the webview fails, otherwise it works.